# Find $c$ such that $y=\frac{1}{2}x+c$ is orthogonal to $f$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Given $f(x) = -\frac{1}{2}x^2 + 6x - 13$, and a line $y = \frac{1}{2}x + c$ that's orthogonal to the graph of $f$.**

Since two graphs are orthogonal when $f'(x)g'(x) = 1$, I have to find a point $p$ where  $f'(p) = -\frac{1}{2}$. $f'(x) = -x + 6$, so $-\frac{1}{2} = -x + 6$ and $x = \frac{13}{2}$.

$f(\frac{13}{2}) = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{13}{2} + 6\frac{13}{2} - 13 = \frac{39}{8}$. Substitute in $y = \frac{1}{2}x + c$: $\frac{39}{8} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{13}{2} + c$, so $c = \frac{13}{8}$.

Too bad this is wrong. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: $f'(x)g'(x) = -1$, not $1$.  So you want a point $p$ such that $f'(p)g'(p) = -1$, and since $g'(x) = 1/2$ for all $x$ then you want $p$ so that $f'(p) = -2$.  Also, it looks like $f(x)$ should be $-\frac12x^{\color{red}{2}} + 6x - 13$, although this doesn't appear to contribute to the overall issue.

Comment: Sloppyness... thanks :) time to stop stuyding again. Blame it on the focus?